# Reading an Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, oledb

```
         Dim connString As String = ""
    Dim strFileType As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower()
    Dim path__1 As String = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

    If strFileType.Trim() = ".xls" Then
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path__1 & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
    ElseIf strFileType.Trim() = ".xlsx" Then
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path__1 & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
    End If
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)

    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
```

> **ON da.Fill(ds)** An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not
>   find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you
>   spell its name and the path name correctly.

[image: Excel File]

Kindly Help Me :(

Comment: Since the error indicates, that the file could possibly be already opened by another process or user, have you tried killing the Excel process before running your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/) library to read Excel files easily.

**Update:**

> EPPlus has from this new major version changed license from LGPL to
> Polyform Noncommercial 1.0.0.
>
> With the new license EPPlus is still free to use in some cases, but
> will require a commercial license to be used in a commercial business.

Answer (score 0):

Put the xls file in a new c:\Temp give full permissions to everyone 
This way you can check if it's  a permissions error. 
Then put your code in a using block which is similar to a try catch block. To understand more read http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/18/447.aspx

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
...

End Using
```

Then you won't need to call dispose or close as end Using will do that for you.